# Como apagar linhas em três tabelas com condição específica (SQL)

Tags: sql, select, delete

Olá. Preciso apagar o conteúdo de um select que coleta linhas de três tabelas, que tem colunas com valores em comum mas que se baseiam em parâmetros de uma única tabela para excluir.

```
select *
from tab1,tab2,tab3
where tab1_col=tab2_col and tab1_col=tab3_col and tab1_status=0 and tab1_numero<2020
```

Eu consigo fazer esse select. O problema é que não estou conseguindo apagar o conteúdo selecionado.

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

O `SELECT` pode ter quantas tabelas quiser, mas o comando `DELETE` deve ser feito um para cada tabela.

Isso deve invalidar fazer um `JOIN` com esse `SELECT`, ou mesmo uma *subquery*, porque após o primeiro `DELETE`, quando fizer o segundo o resultado desse `SELECT` vai mudar, uma vez que os dados não vão mais existir na tabela que foi feito o `DELETE`.

Sugiro inserir esses dados numa tabela temporária. Na sua pergunta não tem o banco de dados que está utilizando, então não dá pra por um exemplo, pois as tabelas temporárias são diferentes para os bancos de dados, mas seria algo assim:

```
-- MySQL: 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dados_para_excluir AS (aqui dentro o seu select)

-- SQL Server:
SELECT * INTO #dados_para_excluir FROM (aqui dentro o seu select)
```

Depois, faça o `DELETE` com cada uma das tabelas, algo assim:

```
delete 
  from tab1
 where id in (select id from dados_para_excluir)
```